# Run 3 public voids in order (after each one has completed its task)

Tags: java, android

I have 3 public voids. The first void parse a pdf file. The second void enhance that pdf file into a string , and the third void uses that string in order to display textviews programmatically (in a for-loop). When all of these voids are called, the app crashes since they're all trying to run at the same time. I want them to wait for each other to complete their task. I don't wanna create a single large void with all the components in it.

How can I call them so that they wait for each other to finish?

Comment: This sounds slightly off to me.  For three methods running in a single thread, if you call them in succession they should execute in serial, not parallel.

Comment: Call each method inside the previous one. I.e.: `MethodA()` calls `MethodB()` and `MethodB()` calls `MethodC()`.

Comment: @ModularSynth Yes...but there might be a more elegant solution involving threading.

Comment: How are the methods running at the same time?  Post some code.

Comment: Why not just call them serially inside a single thread?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Runnable array

**Array:**

```
Runnable[] methods = new Runnable[]{
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("TAG", "1");
                       //1 method
                    }
                },
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("TAG", "2");
                         //2 method
                    }
                },
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("TAG", "3");
                        //3 method
                    }
                }
        };
```

**Call to it:**

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            for (Runnable r : methods)
                service.submit(r);
            service.shutdown();
```